# Unable to publish on aws iot broker with temporary security credentials (STS.assumeRole) over webSocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-sts

I am unable to figure out how to restrict users (with temporary security credentials) to only subscribe to a provided topic on aws IOT.

I am able to connect to aws iot with these temporary security credentials but unable to publish or subscribe.

Below is what i am trying to do in node js.

```
/*
  background information:
      i have allowed all services of iot to this user in aws iam.
      "iot:*". with this if i do not include Policy to
      sts.assumeRole() eveything works, i am subscribed and able to publish.
      But if i include a policy with sts.assumeRole i am unable to
      subscribe or publish.

      Error event of aws-iot-device-sdk.device() never gets called. 

*/
var deviceSdk = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var devic;
var sts = new aws.STS(MyAWSCredentials);
var policy =  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iot:Publish",
   "Resource": "*"
 },
 {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iot:Connect",
   "Resource": "*"
 },
 {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iot:Receive",
   "Resource": "*"
 },


var assumeRoleParams = {
    Policy : JSON.stringify(policy),
    RoleArn : 'arn:aws:iam::226488****:role/assumedRole',
    RoleSessionName : 'ash'
};
sts.assumeRole(assumeRoleParams, function (err,data){
// here we successfully get Credentials.

devic = deviceSdk.device({
  region : 'us-east-1',
  protocol : 'wss',
  accessKeyId : data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
  secretKey : data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
  sessionToken  : data.Credentials.SessionToken,
  port : 443,
  host : 'a2ytgeipo****.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
});

devic.on('connect',function (){
  console.log("connected");

  devic.subscribe('topic2');

  setTimeout(function (){
    devic.publish('topic2',JSON.stringify({msg : "here i come"}));
    // console.log("published");
  },1000);
});

devic.on('message',function (topic,payload){
  console.log(topic);
  console.log(payload.toString());
});

devic.on('error', function (err){
  // never gets called.
  console.log(err);
});
```

});

Comment: I am facing the same problem in browser environment too. When using a temporary credentials from STS (through assumeRoleWithWebIdentity in my case) to establish a websocket connection to IoT, the connection went through but on "connect" was never triggered and both subscribe/publish does nothing.

However, the same code works fine when I use an IAM role. This IAM role and the role being assumed earlier both have the AWSIoTFullAccess policy attached.